# How do I make a url link from a button work from mobile devices as well as desktop PC

Tags: html

I have added 2 buttons to a webpage each with their own URL link. It works perfectly when I click the button from the PC or laptop. However, when I'm on the same webpage on my phone, clicking the buttons does nothing. It is like the button is disabled on mobile devices. I can't work it out.

I've tried searching for different variations of my links but I can't seem to find anything that makes a difference.

HTML Code Used....

```
<form>
 <input style="width: 300px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px; #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #999; -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #999; font-weight: bold; background: #deebc9 ; color: #000; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid #999; font-size: 150%;" type="button" value="Log in" onclick="window.location.href='https://myURLExample/login'" />
</form>
```

Is there a different tag needed for mobile devices?

Comment: This is HTML code I used <form>
<input style="width: 300px; padding: 20px; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px; #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #999; -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #999; font-weight: bold; background: #deebc9 ; color: #000; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid #999; font-size: 150%;" type="button" value="Log in" onclick="window.location.href='https://myExampleURL/login'" />
</form>

Comment: Can you provide your codes ?

Comment: for some reason the code is not showing up in the question text so have added it as a comment

Comment: I suggest you debug the code on the device itself although this should work as is on all devices

Comment: as every body say it should work on every device. Check if JS is activated on your mobile browser. If it's still not working and you only do a navigation, maybe use the a tag <a> with some css style.

Comment: I've found that It's to do with the browser. Works in IE but not on Chrome :-(

Answer (score 0):

Nopes it should work on al the mobile devices make shure u have used right bootstrap classes and cdns for the same I will suggest to check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a `<button />` for this purpose. A button that solely navigates to a different page (as your example code implies) is an anchor link. You're mimicking built-in behaviour.